# Would this work as a multilingual font stack fallback?

Tags: web-applications, fonts, font-face, multilingual, typeface

I have a quick question regarding font fallbacks for a multilingual setup.

I am currently in the process of creating a CMS based application that will target 20 separate languages including Hind, Urdu, Chinese (multiple versions) and Japanese.

My thinking was that I could use some nice typefaces for all latin character set languages then have the Hindi, Urdu etc. languages revert to the system default serif or sans-serif for that language using a CSS font stack like....

```
p { font-family: nicetype, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; }
```

The application will be run on local machines (Mac Mini's with latest OSX) and from iPad's internally so there will be nop need to consider a wider audience other than the Mac Minis and iPads running on the internal network that will access this app.

Would I be right in saying that this font-stack should cut it?

Comment: I'm not sure where the application runs, from where it's viewed, and whether it's a web application or not. You say that "the application will be run on local machines". Do you mean the CMS code will run on the Mac Mini, present a UI of windows and menus, and users will see it like a Mac application?  Or do you mean the CMS will run on a web server and serve HTML pages, and the users will view those pages using the stock web browser on their Mac Mini or iPad? You use the tag *web-applications*, and mention CSS, so I think it's the latter. But I'm not sure.

Comment: By CMS, do you mean "Content Management System"?

Comment: Yes, it's a Content Management System (Joomla! to be precise) nd it will run from a server but be accessed only by Mac Mini's/iPads within the company network that will be connected to the LAN via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a matter of experimentation. Until you have the website up and running with content to display you will not know if it displays properly. The choices you made for your font stack are fairly standard except for the nicetype. The standard line up is:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```